# how to resize image in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an employees from . I want to upload an image for every employee.
and I display the data including image using interactive grid .
but I can't do that.
I tried to using interactive report instead of IG .
but I have to use IG .
the other thing I want to resize the image i have uploaded.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying images in IR, set your image blob column's attributes to -

- Identification > Display Image
- BLOB Attributes > Update/Select corresponding values

Then, give an ID to your IR, example "IR_PHOTO"
Place these CSS in page's CSS > inline

```
#IR_PHOTO img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px; /* any size you want */
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option.

Interactive grid's query:

```
select id,
       apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P3_PHOTO',id) hidden_image,
       null displayed_Image
  from employees
 where id_org = 2;
```

- item `P3_PHOTO` is a "Display image" type item that is based on a BLOB column specified in item source; basically, that's item I use for uploading purposes.
- column `hidden_image` should be hidden (as its name suggests)
- column `displayed_image` should be a "HTML Expression" type, while HTML expression itself is

  ```
  <image src='&HIDDEN_IMAGE.' width=75 height=75>
  ```

Result:

[image]

---

As of resizing images within Apex: why would you want to do that? Prepare images **before** uploading.

Ages ago (comments in my procedure say in 2012), when I had to do that, I used [free batch photo resizer](http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize) which first resized images in a directory (i.e. at operating system level); I then moved them elsewhere (into another directory on a different server), but you can upload them into BLOB column.

Comment: how can i do that using interactive report
?

Comment: Didn't you say "**but I have to use IG**"?